# How to expand a variable "read" from terminal

Tags: bash

For example,

create a bash `tmp.sh` script with the following,

```
export tmp=abc
read _test
echo "$_test"
```

Execute `bash tmp.sh`

Input '$tmp/def'.

Expected result: 'abc/def'

Actual result: '$tmp/def'

Comment: Why should the user of the script know there *is* a variable `tmp` to expand?

Comment: This is an oversimplified example. The case is that tmp is an environment variable to a directory and the user knows that. And they have to input a path to a subdirectory into the variable, say '_test' here, using $tmp/xxx, and then the script knows the path to the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
 eval "echo $_test"
```

or

```
bash -c "echo $_test"
```

**Edit** Latter (`bash -c`) uses sub-shell which is safe in comparison with `eval`

Comment: Obligatory: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4518341) - also applies to executing input.

Comment: Thanks! I have a further problem. Suppose tmp is a directory, and  _test is a subdir in that directory, then echo $(bash -c "$_test"), then it gives a "bash: xxx: is a directory"

Comment: Thanks again! so I can use something like `_test=$(bash -c "echo $_test")` to update it back to the `_test` variable?

Comment: I wouldn't consider `bash -c` much safer than `eval` -- they both have the same basic risk of treating things you thought were just inert pieces of data as executable code. Executing things you didn't think were commands in a subshell isn't much safer than executing them in the main shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `envsubst` command to substitute environment variables like this:

```
echo "$_test" | envsubst
```

or, since this is in bash:

```
envsubst <<<"$_test"
```

This is significantly safer than either `eval` or `bash -c`, since it won't do anything *other* than replacing instances of `$var` or `${var}` with the corresponding variable values.